# Windows - Search for Files that Do NOT Contain a Certain Term

Tags: search, windows-xp

How would I search for anything in a certain directory that **doesn't** contain a certain term?

For example:

```
!(FINAL)
```

or

```
NOT(FINAL)
```

I would like to find anything (files only) that doesn't contain the term `FINAL` in the title in Windows XP.  Is this possible?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Windows Command Prompt

To do this with Windows Command Prompt, CMD.

Start -> Run -> Type "cmd". use "cd" to change to your working directory and enter:

```
dir | findstr /v /i "FINAL"
```

This will list all **files and folders** which do not have the word "*FINAL*" in the title.

```
dir /a:-d | findstr /v /i "FINAL"
```

This will list all **files** which do not have the word "*FINAL*" in the title.

### POWERSHELL

It is possible to do this with Windows PowerShell.

```
Get-ChildItem -exclude "*FINAL*"
```

This will list all **files and folders** which do not have the word "*FINAL*" in the title.

```
Get-ChildItem -exclude "*FINAL*" | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
```

This will list all **files** which do not have the word "*FINAL*" in the title.

You may need to download and install Windows PowerShell from here if your installation of XP does not already have it. [Windows XP Powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7217)

**Useful Links.**

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176841.aspx

Comment: @MobyDisk You are stating this weirdly - stdin is a file descriptor that can represent a file, or input into the program.  A list of files from dir piped to stdin looks the same as if you "cat"-ed a file that contained a list of files.  Long and short, there is nothing wrong with the above pipe.

Comment: The windows command can be augmented with /S to get subdirectories.  "dir /A-D /S".    The colon is optional.

Answer (score 16):

You can search for `* NOT *FINAL*` for example to find anything without the string final in it

Comment: The benefit of this answer and `siryx` answer below (either using NOT or using minus sign - inside the Windows Explorer search GUI tool) is that you can turn on `Advanced Options > In non-indexed locations > File contents` to search within the contents of text documents and find those missing certain text, not just searching inside the document title.

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking for something right from your explorer window, I just did some research since these answers here didnt suffice to me.

To find all php files which do not have "decoded" in their name, I put the following in the search field:

```
*.php -Decoded
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

In Windows File Explorer Search Box, type: -

NAME:AAAA (to find documents with AAAA in the title)

NAME:AAAA AND NAME:BBBB (to find documents with both AAAA and BBB in the title)

NAME:XXXX AND NOT:YYY (to find documents with XXXX in the title, but not YYY)

Answer (score 1):

For what is worth, if you do have Total Commander (https://www.ghisler.com/index.htm), it has a pretty good search functionality. 
It is able to look into files and has an explicit checkbox **"Find files not containing the text"**

(note: I am not affiliated with Total Commander in any way, but it is a good tool)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10 file explorer...

green NOT blue (Shows all files with "green" in the name, but not files with "blue" in the name)

. NOT backup (Shows all files containing a period(.) before the file extension(which should be all of them), but not files containing the word "backup")

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code like this:

```
grep -rin "find-what?" ./
```

You need cmd-bash for this. Makes the work easier!

Comment: Thanks for this, but I was hoping for something that could be applied directly from the Windows Explorer window.  Any other suggestions?